# Correct name for (dynamic?) widgets

Tags: applications, app-widgets, user-interface

What is the correct name for these kind of widgets that reflect the current time, date, weather etc (introduced in Android 8, I think) ?

Screenshot from home screen of Pixel 4a,Android 11, using Nova Launcher 7, with icon theme set to system

[image]

Dynamic (as in title) makes sense functionally but it doesn't seem to be the technical name. I want to ask an app developer to implement this and describe it correctly.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, those are actually *app icons*, not app widgets. Stack Overflow has a related question about this: [Is there any way to dynamically change an app icon like Calendar app does?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34592230/2821954). Not sure if [adaptive icons since Android 8.0](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) is related or not.

Comment: @AndrewT, Thanks. Didn't know both are different! Wonder how they are defined differently. Maybe you can explain?

Comment: I need some time to read more about it since this looks like a hack (need integration with the launcher app to update it) instead of a normal, standalone widget (can update freely, independent of the launcher app)

Comment: @AndrewT, if it helps, Android 11,Pixel 4a, Nova Launcher. I can see clock for example on home screen reflecting current time (as in question) as also in app drawer as mentioned in one of the answers there

Comment: Andrew seems to be correct. I just noticed they have titles too. They can be [App Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts). Are they default icons of the apps?

Comment: @AndrewT,  changed the icon theme and current information (time) is not shown

Comment: Well, then definitely they are not widgets. Widgets are to be added by the user, they don't appear as the only app icon.

Comment: Launchers which support App Widgets have a dedicated section listing all the available widgets from all the installed apps. User can select to add (or drag and drop) one of the widgets on the home screen. App drawer (which lists app icons of all the installed launch-able apps) and the widgets list screen are different sections. Widgets list is usually accessible by long pressing the empty area on home screen (or may be from the settings of the Launcher app; it's developer's choice). Related: https://support.google.com/android/answer/9450271.

Comment: And App Shortcuts are usually available by long pressing the app icon (or the app may create one dynamically depending on the user's actions within the app). So the App Icons, App Shortcuts, and App Widgets are three different things. And they have further categories too.

Comment: And as it seems, if they are the default icons of the apps, they must be just the (dynamic) app icons, neither app shortcuts, nor app widgets.